# Oracle Nested Select returns ORA-00913 "too many values"

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I get the **ORA-00913: "too many values"** error while nesting a pivot sql into another sql.

How can I correct this or is there a simpler way to write this as I need the "NEEDTHISFIELD" field for another program.

```sql
SELECT null as NEEDTHISFIELD, (SELECT * FROM(
SELECT th.BUCHDAT,th.OID,th.EFTYP,ef.NAME,thp.XORDER,thp.THEVALUE
FROM THISTORY th
LEFT JOIN EFTYP ef on th.EFTYP = ef.OID
LEFT JOIN THPARA thp on th.OID = thp.THISTORY
WHERE th.EFTYP = 'xyz'
)
PIVOT (MAX(THEVALUE) FOR (XORDER) IN (
 '100' AS "VAL1",
 '101' AS "VAL2"
)))
FROM DUAL;
```

Many thanks!

Comment: `SELECT` In a `SELECT` has to be returning only one row and one column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your nested query return more that one record.
Try something like this

```
SELECT null as NEEDTHISFIELD,t.* FROM(
SELECT th.BUCHDAT,th.OID,th.EFTYP,ef.NAME,thp.XORDER,thp.THEVALUE
FROM THISTORY th
LEFT JOIN EFTYP ef on th.EFTYP = ef.OID
LEFT JOIN THPARA thp on th.OID = thp.THISTORY
WHERE th.EFTYP = 'xyz'
)
PIVOT (MAX(THEVALUE) FOR (XORDER) IN (
 '100' AS "VAL1",
 '101' AS "VAL2"
) t ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just include an alias for the pivoted table then you can add it the required field to the list of selected fields:

```
SELECT t.*,
       NULL AS NeedThisField
FROM   ( SELECT th.BUCHDAT,
                th.OID,
                th.EFTYP,
                ef.NAME,
                thp.XORDER,
                thp.THEVALUE
         FROM   THISTORY th
                LEFT JOIN EFTYP ef on th.EFTYP = ef.OID
                LEFT JOIN THPARA thp on th.OID = thp.THISTORY
         WHERE  th.EFTYP = 'xyz'
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(THEVALUE)
  FOR (XORDER) IN ( '100' AS "VAL1", '101' AS "VAL2" )
) t;
```